# Como comparar em update

Tags: php, sql-update

O código principal é este:

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));

$query = "SELECT id_medico as txtid, nome as txtNome, email as txtEmail, telemovel as txtTelemovel, morada as txtMorada, especialidade as txtEspecialidade, NIF as txtNif, Localidade as txtLocalidade, codigo_postal as txtCodigo, data_nascimento as txtnascimento, observacoes as txtObservacao  FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       
$meujson = array();   


?>
<div id=Corpo>
<br>
    <br>
<form name="medicos" method="post" action="">
<label for="cbMedicos">Selecione um M&eacute;dico</label>
<select id="cbMedicos" name="cbMedicos">
<option>Selecione...</option>

<?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo '<option value="'.$prod['txtid'].'">'.$prod['txtNome'].'</option>';
    $meujson[$prod['txtid']] = $prod; // coleciona as linhas no $meujson
     $_SESSION[$prod['txtid']] = $prod['txtid'];

   }
   ?>
</select>

<br> <br> <br>

&nbsp &nbsp <label for="txtid">Nome:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtNome" name="txtNome" value="" size=90 /> <br> <br>
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">NIF:</label> &nbsp &nbsp
<input type="number" id="txtNif" name="txtNif" value="" /> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
&nbsp
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">Data de Nascimento:</label> &nbsp
<input type="date" id="txtdata" name="txtdata" value="" /> <br> <br>
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">Email:</label> 
<input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail"value="" size=30 /> &nbsp 
&nbsp
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">Telem&oacute;vel:</label>
<input type="number" id="txtTelemovel" name="txtTelemovel" value="" /> <br> 
<br>
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">Morada:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtMorada" name="txtMorada" value="" size=90 /> <br> 
<br>
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">C&oacute;digo Postal:</label>
<input type="number" id="txtCodigo" name="txtCodigo" value="" /> 
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">Localidade:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtLocalidade" name="txtLocalidade"value="" /> <br> 
<br>
 &nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">Especialidade:</label>
 <input type="text" id="txtEspecialidade" name="txtEspecialidade" value="" /><br> <br>
 &nbsp &nbsp<label for="txtid">Observa&ccedil;&otilde;es:</label>
 <input type="text" id="txtObservacao" name="txtObservacao" value="" size=90/><br> <br>


<script type="text/javascript">

var dados = <?php echo json_encode($meujson); ?>;
document.getElementById("cbMedicos").addEventListener("change", function () 
{
var linha = dados[this.value];
for (var ch in linha) {
    (document.getElementById(ch) || {}).value = linha[ch];
}
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("cbMedicos").addEventListener("change", function () 
{
    document.getElementById("txtid").value = this.value;
});
</script>

        <br>
    <br>
    <br> 


        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="submit" value="Novo" class="botaoNovo" name="botao_novo"> 
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="reset" value="Apagar" class="botaoApagar" name="botao_apagar"> 
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="botaoEditar" name="botao_editar"> 
        </div>
        </form>
```

E depois o código abaixo é chamado à página principal.
E quero que na query update compare o nome da base de dados com o nome escolhido da combobox, eu tinha colocado assim:

```
....
$cbnome= trim($_POST['cbMedicos']);

$query = "UPDATE Medicos SET nome= '".$Nome."', NIF='".$nif."', data_nascimento='".$bday."', email='".$email."', telemovel='".$telemovel."', morada='".$morada."', codigo_postal= '".$codigo."', Localidade= '".$localidade."', especialidade= '".$especialidade."', observacoes= '".$observacao."' WHERE nome = '$cbnome'";  
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);

if ($result == 0) 
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO Medicos (nome, NIF, telemovel, data_nascimento, email, morada , observacoes, codigo_postal,   especialidade, Localidade )  VALUES ('".$Nome."', '".$nif."', '".$telemovel."', '".$bday."', '".$email."', '".  $morada."', '".$observacao."', '".$codigo."', '".$especialidade."', '".$localidade."')";

    $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

    echo  "<br>Dados do pacientes gravados com sucesso <br>";
}

else
{
   echo "<br> O novo paciente foi inserido com sucesso <br>";
}


?>
<?php
    }
    mysqli_close($dbconn);
    ?>
```

mas não está a funcionar, alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Sua `query` parece estar certa, tente escreve-la diretamente no `SQL` e veja se retorna algum erro, ou algo fora do comum.

Comment: @Francisco já fiz isso, mas no sql não dá para colocar com os nomes das labels e eu acho que o problema estará no WHERE

Comment: Dê um insert só para testes e execute a query simulando alguns valores.

Comment: @Francisco editei a pergunta e coloquei todo o código... Ele faz sempre o insert, nunca faz o update.

Comment: $row['txtid_medico'];  Não seria  $prod['txtid_medico'];? Outra coisa quem é txtid_medico?

Comment: Eu nunca tinha utilizado essa linha de código, deram-me essa linha para guardar uma variável e ser chamada noutro ficheiro PHP, eu adaptei à combobox, mas o id_medico está errado é txtid...  Já edito a pergunta, mas neste caso essa linha não é chamada a este código...

Comment: continua errado não é $row['txtid'] e sim $prod['txtid']

Comment: $dbconn !=$dbcon  Está usando mysqli_query($dbconn  e na hora de fechar a conexão está  mysqli_close($dbcon

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo  já editei o código mas continua igual...

Comment: Não estou dizendo que esses erros iriam corrigir o update, são só detalhes. Estou criando um ambiente no meu server/banco pra testar seu script

Comment: Poderia postar o HTML também

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo já editei o meu código com o que tenho

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente na linha do update  `WHERE nome = '$cbnome'` tem um erro.

Essa variável  `$cbnome` não se refere a coluna `nome` e sim a coluna `id_medico`

Portanto o correto é   `WHERE id_medico = '$cbnome'";`

> essa variável `$cbnome` foi mal nomeada e com isso causando alguma confusão.

### Tem mais erros

este trecho de código

```
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);

if ($result == 0) 
{
```

não funciona corretamente, ele faz update e insert independentemente do botão clicado  `Novo`  ou  `Editar`

**Da forma abaixo apresentado vai funcionar corretamente:**

```
if ($_POST['botao_novo'] == "Novo") 
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO Medicos (nome, NIF, telemovel, data_nascimento, email, morada , observacoes, codigo_postal,   especialidade, Localidade )  VALUES ('".$Nome."', '".$nif."', '".$telemovel."', '".$bday."', '".$email."', '".  $morada."', '".$observacao."', '".$codigo."', '".$especialidade."', '".$localidade."')";

    $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

    echo  "<br> O novo paciente foi inserido com sucesso<br>";
}

if ($_POST['botao_editar'] == "Editar") 
{
   $query = "UPDATE Medicos SET nome= '".$Nome."', NIF='".$nif."', data_nascimento='".$bday."', email='".$email."', telemovel='".$telemovel."', morada='".$morada."', codigo_postal= '".$codigo."', Localidade= '".$localidade."', especialidade= '".$especialidade."', observacoes= '".$observacao."' WHERE id_medico = '$cbnome'"; 

   $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

   echo "<br> Dados do paciente atualizados com sucesso <br>";
}
```

> Caso não se possa inserir novos com algum critério pré-estabelecido, por exemplo, pelo email, há que se fazer uma verificação da existência desse antes do insert.

Exemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM Medicos Where email= '$email'";
$data_mail = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result_mail = mysqli_num_rows($data_mail); 


    if ($result_mail == 0) 
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO Medicos (nome, NIF, telemovel, data_nascimento, email, morada , observacoes, codigo_postal,   especialidade, Localidade )  VALUES ('".$Nome."', '".$nif."', '".$telemovel."', '".$bday."', '".$email."', '".  $morada."', '".$observacao."', '".$codigo."', '".$especialidade."', '".$localidade."')";

        $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

        echo  "<br> O novo paciente foi inserido com sucesso<br>";
    }
    else 
    {

       $query = "UPDATE Medicos SET nome= '".$Nome."', NIF='".$nif."', data_nascimento='".$bday."', email='".$email."', telemovel='".$telemovel."', morada='".$morada."', codigo_postal= '".$codigo."', Localidade= '".$localidade."', especialidade= '".$especialidade."', observacoes= '".$observacao."' WHERE id_medico = '$cbnome'"; 
       $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

       echo "<br> Dados do paciente atualizados com sucesso <br>";
    }
```

> Nesse caso basta um botão submit, e o insert só se dará caso haja mudança de email no campo email

Comment: se tirar o botão novo, ficar apenas um único botão que faz uma das duas coisas, conforme se já existe aquele nome ou não, é possível?

Comment: Pode haver nesse mundo dois medicos com mesmo nome!!! pode ser feito por exemplo pelo mail, esse é unico

Comment: É uma boa opção mas como consegui fazer o código? Era isso que estava a tentar fazer com os ifs... fazia um ou fazia outro conforme se já existisse ou não.

Comment: @IsabelSousa, sim é possivel. É só fazer um SELECT.... WHERE email = '$email'  e depois verificar com mysqli_num_rows e fazer if ($result_mail == 0) update else insert

Comment: Vou colocar essa outra opção na resposta, só que vai entrar mais processamento

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava nesta linha de código: em vez de     "'.$prod['txtid'].'" fica:

```
echo '<option value="'.$prod['txtNome'].'">'.$prod['txtNome'].'</option>';
```

Sendo que a query passa a:

```
UPDATE Medicos SET nome= '".$Nome."', NIF='".$nif."', data_nascimento='".$bday."', email='".$email."', telemovel='".$telemovel."', morada='".$morada."', codigo_postal= '".$codigo."', Localidade= '".$localidade."', especialidade= '".$especialidade."', observacoes= '".$observacao."' WHERE nome = '$cbnome'";
```

Comment: E se duas pessoas tiverem o mesmo nome?

Comment: @Everson, ai blau blau :)